# If a fair die is rolled 10 times, what is the probability that number 5 appears 3 times and the number 6 appears 2 times?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

**Question.**

> If a fair die is rolled 10 times,  what is the probability that number
> 5 appears exactly 3 times and the number 6 appears exactly 2 times?

**Attempt.**
$$
P(E)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{5}\times10!}{2!3!5!}\cong0.042
$$

Is there a way to solve it using binomial distribution?

Comment: Do you mean that $5$ should occur *exactly* $3$ times or *at least* $3$ times (same question for the $6$).

Comment: exactly for both

Comment: I suggest editing your post to clarify that point.

Comment: done thank you for comment

Comment: With that clarification, I agree with your computation

Comment: @lulu Is there a way to solve it using binomial distribution?

Comment: I don't see how, it's not a binomial process.  We are counting the occurrences of three different events, not two.  I think what you wrote is optimal.

Comment: ok, thank you mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that $5$ appears exactly three times. Let $X$ have Binomial$(10,1/6)$ distribution, and let $Y$ have Binomial$(7,1/5)$ distribution. Given $A$,  the remaining tosses are independent of each other, and each of them   has five equally likely options. Thus
$$P(E)=P(A)P(E|A)=P(X=3)P(Y=2)$$ $$ ={10 \choose 3}(\frac16)^3(\frac56)^7 \cdot{7 \choose 2}(\frac15)^2 (\frac45)^5 \,.$$
This agrees with your solution.

Comment: Math typesetting tip: `(\frac16)^3` gives $(\frac16)^3$, but `\left(\frac16\right)^3` gives $\left(\frac16\right)^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Instead of regarding the problem as a *probability of events* problem, regard it as a Combinatorics problem, which is my favorite way of attacking such problems.  The probability is expressed as

$$\frac{N}{D}, \tag1 $$

where $~D = 6^{(10)},~$ which equals the total number of different results that can occur, when a die is rolled $(10)$ times.

Then

$$N = \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2} \times 4^5. \tag2$$

In (2) above, the first factor represents the number of distinct ways that the three $(5)$'s can be placed.  Then, the second factor represents the number of distinct ways that the two $(6)$'s can be placed, in the $7$ remaining positions, after the three $(5)$'s are placed.

Then, in (2) above, the third factor represents the number of ways that the five *other* (unrestricted) postions can occur, where there are four different numbers possible for each of these unrestricted positions.

So

$$N = 120 \times 21 \times 1024 = 2580480$$

and

$$D = 6^{(10)} = 60466176.$$

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{2580480}{60466176} \approx (0.042676).$$